# Backbone Model Fetch refresh event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I hope i can abstract all the relevant parts. My question is why the render method isn't executing when i fetch my model from the server.

**Model**

```
var Document = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/dms/reconcile/GetDocumentByDocumentId/"
});
```

**View**

```
window.DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#reconcile_document"),
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('refresh', this.render) //also tried reset
    },
    render: function () {

        alert("Do awesome stuff here");

        return this;
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
        var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "package/:id": "getPackage"
            },
            getPackage: function (packageid, p) {

                window._document = new Document({ id:packageid) });
                window.document = new DocumentView({ model: _document });

                _document.fetch();
            }
        });

        // Instantiate the router
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
```

So when i go to `localhost:3000/#/Package/123` I can see that the xhr call to `localhost:3000/dms/reconcile/GetDocumentByDocumentId/123` and the data comes back successfully but the `render` function never executes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `fetch()` on a model won't fire a `refresh` event. It will fire a `change` event by calling `set` after it fetches the data:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-40

and

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch

Change your event handler and it should work:

```
window.DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#reconcile_document"),
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {

        alert("Do awesome stuff here");

        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, you can call _document.fetch({success: _document.success_handler}). And in success_handler, you can trigger a custom event on your model.

Comment: I appreciate it Derick, i totally overlooked that in the doc. But it turns out i also needed to set the response to the model in the parse method in the document model. Thanks for your help.